# Open the google drive url in iframe

Tags: google-drive-api

is there any ways to open the google drive page on my website in iframe as the user is login with oauth google login and have the auth session of his and l have also passed the scope during the auth so that we can access the google drive api completely, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not embed Google Drive itself in an iframe. You have the choice of using:

1. `embedLink` to embed a viewer for the file (needs correct cookie auth)
2. `exportLinks` to export the file to a viewable format

Neither of these will give you the full Google Drive editor, sorry, but that is only available from Google.